# How to convert HEX string to Float (Little Endian)

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, type-conversion

I just learned Python (3.x) and I am stuck with HEX String conversion to Float. I have this HEX String values:
`'0x22354942F31AFA42CE6A494311518A43082CAF437C6BD4C35F78FA433BF10F442A5222448D3D3544200749C438295C4468AF6E4406B4804450518A4423B0934450E99CC4'`
And I want to turn it into float.

I have tried to use this code:

```
bs=bytes.fromhex(row[2:])
fmt = '<' + ('H' * (len(bs) // 2))
res=struct.unpack(fmt, bs)
```

and it gives me the result of `13602.0,16969.0,6899.0,17146.0,27342.0,17225.0,20753.0,17290.0,11272.0,17327.0,27516.0,50132.0,30815.0,17402.0,61755.0,17423.0,21034.0,17442.0,15757.0,17461.0,1824.0,50249.0,10552.0,17500.0,44904.0,17518.0,46086.0,17536.0,20816.0,17546.0,45091.0,17555.0,59728.0,50332.0`

After checking it, I found out that the code that what I currently have is float in base 16, while I need it in base 32 (or maybe not because I am not sure what base/format), with expected float results as `50.3018875, 125.052635,201.4172,276.633331,350.344,424.839722,500.9404,575.7692,649.2838,724.961731,804.1113,880.644043,954.7407,1029.62573,106.541,1181.50427,1255.291` the values which I got from this [Calculator Converter](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/).
What should I change in the coding to get the expected results?
Thank you.

Comment: `bs:` is not valid python (the first line). Did you mean `bs = `? Also, can you give a complete example of input and output (with no `...`). It's unclear how things are encoded. The hex you have is 136 bytes. That's likely either 17 IEEE doubles (64 bit floating point numbers) or 34 IEEE floats (32 bit floating point numbers).

Comment: What does float in base 16/base 32 even mean? Are your hex values a representation of ieee floats or are they digits in a float? If the latter, where is the fractaional separator? (The dot?)

Comment: I made typo when I wrote it on the question, I just edited it on the question, yes, I meant bs=. 
The current output which I got is `13602.0,16969.0,6899.0,17146.0,27342.0,17225.0,20753.0,17290.0,11272.0,17327.0,27516.0,50132.0,30815.0,17402.0,61755.0,17423.0,21034.0,17442.0,15757.0,17461.0,1824.0,50249.0,10552.0,17500.0,44904.0,17518.0,46086.0,17536.0,20816.0,17546.0,45091.0,17555.0,59728.0,50332.0`

Comment: The expected results: `50.3018875, 125.052635,201.4172,276.633331,350.344,424.839722,500.9404,575.7692,649.2838,724.961731,804.1113,880.644043,954.7407,1029.62573,106.541,1181.50427,1255.291` @BaileyParker Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break things down here, because you seem to be confused a bit with all of the juggling of representations. You have some hexadecimal string (that's base 16 encoding) of some binary data. That's your `0x22354942F31AFA42CE6A494311...`. You correctly identified that you can convert this from its encoded form to python `bytes` with `bytes.fromhex`:

```
hex_encoded = '0x22354942F31AFA42CE6A494311518A43082CAF437C6BD4C35F78FA433BF10F442A5222448D3D3544200749C438295C4468AF6E4406B4804450518A4423B0934450E99CC4'
binary_data = bytes.fromhex(hex_encoded[2:])  # we do 2: to remove the leading '0x'
```

At this point, unless we know how `binary_data` was constructed we can't do anything. But we can take some guesses. You know the first few numbers are floating points: `50.3018875, 125.052635, 201.4172, ...`. Typically floats are encoded using the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). This provides 3 different encodings of a floating point number: binary16 (16 bits), float (32 bits), and double (64 bits). You can see these in the [struct documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html#format-characters), they are format codes `'e'`, `'f'`, and `'d'`, respectively. We can try each to see which of (if any) your binary data is encoded as. By trial and error, we discover your data was encoded as 32-bit floats, so you can decode them with:

```
FLOAT = 'f'
fmt = '<' + FLOAT * (len(binary_data) // struct.calcsize(FLOAT))
numbers = struct.unpack(fmt, binary_data)
print(numbers)
```

Why did what you tried not work? Well you used the format code `'H'` which is for an unsigned short. This is an *integer*, which is why you were getting back numbers with no fractional part!

Comment: yeahh, I was so confused on the representations. Thank you very much! finally, it works!! And just wondering, some values of the result is negative, is there any way to format it to make is absolute? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If some of the numbers come out of `struct.unpack` as negative, then that means that was how they were encoded. But you can `map(abs, numbers)` to get the absolute value of all of the numbers.