# Omron Sysmac - convert hex to signed floating point decimal

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am working on an Omron system and I am trying to generate a printout of all of the retained setpoints. It would take me days to do this manually, so I created a variable backup in Sysmac. This file is exported as an XML format which is great, but the export converts all of my real tags to hexadecimal. Some of these tags are signed floating-point decimals and I am not sure how to convert these back to readable values. I am using python to process the file. Here are some examples of the items I need to convert:

```
  <Item Name="VAR://****_**.IO.OFST" DataType="REAL">
    <Data>7F138ABD</Data>
  </Item>
  <Item Name="VAR://****_**.ALPHA" DataType="REAL">
    <Data>6F1203BC</Data>
  </Item>
```

Both of these numbers are negative floating-point decimals. I have been at this for a few hours now and figured I wouldn't hurt to ask for some help. I would greatly appreciate any direction on the topic!

Answer (score 0):

I found a python solution. Here it is if anyone else is looking

[How to convert HEX string to Float (Little Endian)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329438/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-float-little-endian)

```
import struct

hex_val = '7F138ABD'

binary_data = bytes.fromhex(hex_val)

FLOAT = 'f'
fmt = '<' + FLOAT * (len(binary_data) // struct.calcsize(FLOAT))
numbers = struct.unpack(fmt, binary_data)
print(numbers[0])
```